# Join or interpolate broken lines

Tags: qgis, line, merge, attribute-joins

I have these lines (**blues lines**) that extract from a raster and need to unite them automatically (**red lines**).
Currently I'm doing it manually using a plugin (Join multiple lines) but it's very tiring. Is there any way to grow and join the lines automatically? I thought of joining based on the angle of inclination but I do not know how to proceed.
I use QGIS and Ecognition.

What I have:

[image: What i have:]

What I want:

[image: What i want]

Comment: By merging rows, do you mean merge the line segments to form continuous lines? But still have each individual line be separate from the one below?

Comment: What are the red and blue lines in your diagram? Which lines are you trying to "unite", and with what? Are you trying to figure out which blue lines the red segments are on?

Comment: I made changes to the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Have you found a solution?